# android initializeScrollbars() - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, scrollbar, indexoutofboundsexception

Since i last compiled my project I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but i havent changed any code there...

Im programmatically enabling scrollbars on my `MyView`
but since today it fails executing `initializeScrollbars()`

The buggy code is:

```
TypedArray a = Utilities.context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[0]);
initializeScrollbars(a);
a.recycle();
```

And here the Exception:

```
W/System.err( 2140): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=264
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getResourceId(TypedArray.java:571)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getBoolean(XResources.java:868)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.view.View.initializeScrollbars(View.java:4188)
W/System.err( 2140):    at de.mytest.testapp.MyView.<init>(MyView.java:77)
W/System.err( 2140):    at de.mytest.testapp.Main.onCreate(Main.java:74)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 2140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5141)
W/System.err( 2140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 2140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
W/System.err( 2140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
W/System.err( 2140):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
W/System.err( 2140):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```